# Simple sum with $i = 2$ step

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to calculate the following sum:

$$S_{n} = \sum_{2 \leq i \leq n  } (3i - 2)$$

(two more conditions for the above sum: $n$ is even and $i$ **with step** $2$ (not sure how to do multi-line))

Adding image of the task with multi-line visible:

[image]

I wrote down the first few terms and it looks like this:

$4, 10, 16, 22, ...$

I re-arranged a bit and obtained such sum:

$$S_{n} = \sum_{i = 0}^{n} 4+6i$$

and its terms are the same: $4, 10, 16, 22, ...$

Is the top boundary correct?

Proceeding with the solution:

$$S_{n} = \sum_{i = 0}^{n} 4+6i$$

$$S_{n} = 4 \sum_{i = 0}^{n} + 6 \sum_{i = 0}^{n} i$$

$$S_{n} = 4n + 4 + 6 \sum_{i = 0}^{n} i$$

$$S_{n} = 4n + 4 + 6 \frac{(1+n)n}{2}$$

$$S_{n} = 4n + 4 + 3 (n^2 + n)$$

$$S_{n} = 3n^2 + 7n + 4$$

Testing for $n = 3$:

$$S_{3} = 3(3^2) + 21 + 4 = 52 = \Bigg(4 + 10 + 16 + 22 \Bigg)$$

So the result seems correct. But is it for sure? Plugging $3$ into $n$ should take into account only first $3$ or first $4$ elements? (works fine for first $4$ elements, but seems kinda wrong for me)

Comment: Yes it is, you can prove it by induction

Comment: "Is the top boundary correct?"  You should notice... how many terms are being added in total originally?  Worded again, how many terms are there in the set $\{2,3,4,\dots,n\}$?  Well... we know how many terms there are in $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$, right?  And $\{2,3,\dots,n\}$ is different than that how?  Now, compare this to how many terms there are in $\{0,1,2,\dots,n\}$.  So, in your original sum, how many terms were being added?  In your new sum how many terms were being added?  Just because the first few terms match wasn't enough to say the overall sum was the same, you have to end together

Comment: Another, perhaps easier approach that you might prefer is noting that $\sum\limits_{2\leq i\leq n} f(i) = \left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^n f(i)\right) - f(0)-f(1)$

Comment: define as $S_{n} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} 4+6(i-1)$, then all be fine.

Comment: @farruhota This seems to produce the right result, thanks. By the way, is $a_{0}$ a thing, or the first term in arithmetic series should always be $a_{1}$?

Comment: usually, the [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) starts with $a_1$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Although the trick with subtracting $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ I think wouldn't work for my case, it's still something that I will remember of in the future. Thanks. I think it'd not work in my case, because if I'd calculate $\sum_{i=0}^{n} f(i)$, then I'd also need to subtract all the odd $i$, that is: $f(3), f(5), f(7), f(9), ...$.

Comment: Ah, I missed the condition that $i$ only ranges over the even values.  That wasn't terribly clear originally.  As to your question on "is $a_0$ a thing" that is entirely personal preference on a case to case basis.  There are situations where I prefer to start at $a_0$ while others I might not.  Most programming languages (but not all) start indexing arrays and lists at zero and plugging in zero to most functions is terribly easy, reinforcing the convenience of starting at zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We consider the original task 
>   \begin{align*}
>   S_N=\sum_{{2\leq i\leq N}\atop{i\ \mathrm{with\  step\ } 2}}\left(3i-2\right)\qquad\qquad N\mathrm{\  even}
>   \end{align*}

We calculate for small $N=2,4,6$ (considering even $N$ only)
\begin{align*}
  S_2&=\sum_{{2\leq i\leq 2}\atop{i\ \mathrm{with\ step\ } 2}}(3i-2)=3\cdot 2-2=4\\
  S_4&=\sum_{{2\leq i\leq 4}\atop{i\ \mathrm{with\ step\ } 2}}(3i-2)=(3\cdot 2-2)+(3\cdot 4-2)=4+10=14\\
  S_6&=\sum_{{2\leq i\leq 6}\atop{i\ \mathrm{with\ step\ } 2}}(3i-2)=(3\cdot 2-2)+(3\cdot 4-2)+(3\cdot 6-2)=4+10+16=30\\  
  \end{align*}

> Generally we obtain for even $N$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{S_N}&=\sum_{{2\leq i\leq N}\atop{{i\ \mathrm{with\ step\ }2}}}\left(3i-2\right)\\
> &=\sum_{{i=2}\atop {i\ \mathrm{with\ step\ }2}}^N\left(3i-2\right)\\
> &=\sum_{i=1}^{N/2}\left(3(2i)-2\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=6\sum_{i=1}^{N/2}i-2\sum_{i=1}^{N/2}1\\
> &=6\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{N}{2}\left(\frac{N}{2}+1\right)-2\cdot\frac{N}{2}\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{3}{4}N^2+\frac{1}{2}N}
> \end{align*}
>   which gives for small values of $N$: $S_2=4,S_4=14,S_6=30$ as expected.

Comment:

- In (1) we respect the step-width $2$ of $i$ by substituting $i$ with $2i$. We also have to set the lower limit to $1$ and the upper limit to $N/2$ as compensation.
- In (2) we use the finite geometric sum formula $\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$.

> **Hint:** Your sum $S_n$ is not correct, since there are brackets missing and an index shift was not appropriately performed. But it can be easily corrected. We have with $n=\frac{N}{2}$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{{i=2}\atop{\mathrm{step\ width}\ 2}}^{N}(3i-2)&=\sum_{i=1}^{N/2}\color{blue}{(}3(2i)-2\color{blue}{)}\\
> &=\sum_{i=1}^n\color{blue}{(}6i-2\color{blue}{)}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{\color{blue}{n-1}}\color{blue}{(}6i+4\color{blue}{)}\\
> &=\ldots
> \end{align*}
>
> which gives for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ the sequence $4,14,30,\ldots$ as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

This is $$3\sum_{i=2}^n i-2\sum_{i=2}^n 1=$$

Comment: $i$ has to be even as mentioned above.

Comment: May I ask... the task says "$i$ with step $2$". Did it mean that the $i$ simply starts from $2$, or did it mean that I am increasing $i$ by $2$?
So `i = i + 2` instead of "standard" `i = i + 1`

Comment: I was convinced that "$i$ with step $2$" means that the $i$ increases by $2$ everytime, instead of $1$. So I am considering only $f(2), f(4), f(6), f(8), ...$ rather than $f(2), f(3), f(4), f(5), ...$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct: maybe you wouldn't have done so many calculations, if you changed from $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}f(i)$ to $\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^n f(i)\right) - f(0)-f(1)$. Then calculate $f_{0}$ and $f{1}$ and substatract them in the final formula.

Comment: But how does it take into account that $i$ has to be even?

Comment: I am considering only $i$ from the set \{ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, ... \}.

Comment: Sorry, corrected. I'm trefering to the second sum: $S_{n} = \sum_{i = 0}^{n} 4+6i$

Answer (score 1):

Make the substitution $j=i-2$: $$S_n=\sum_{i=2}^{n}(3i-2) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-2}[3(j+2)-2] = \sum_{j=0}^{n-2}(3j+4) = 3 \cdot \sum_{j=0}^{n-2} j + 4 \cdot \sum_{j=0}^{n-2} 1 .$$ Now use the well known formula $\sum_{j=0}^{m} j = \frac{m(m+1)}{2}$ and get 
$$ S_n = 3 \cdot \frac{(n-2)(n-1)}{2} + 4 \cdot (n-1) = \frac{3n^2-9n+6+8n-8}{2} = \frac{3n^2-n-2}{2} = \frac{(3n+2)(n-1)}{2}.$$